# Missing attachment from Outlook JS Api

Tags: javascript, office-js, outlook-web-addins

I'm creating an Outlook add-in and I would like to get each attachment from a mail using JavaScript.

So far, it worked fine with this:

```
var attch = Office.context.mailbox.item.attachments;    
for(i = 0; i < attch.length; i++) {
    // Logic here
}
```

But today, I found that an `.msi` file was missing from the `attch` variable. I think that's because this file is an executable and thus is considered as dangerous

As a workaround, I know that I can do an AJAX Request to my ASP.Net webserver and consume Exchange API to get the full attachment list :

```
var exService = new ExchangeService
{
    Url = new Uri(data.EwsURL),
    Credentials = new WebCredentials(data.Login, data.Password)
};

var message = EmailMessage.Bind(exService, new ItemId(data.mailId));
var propertySet = new PropertySet(ItemSchema.Attachments);

message.Load(propertySet);

if (message.Attachments.Count == 0 || data.Type == "text" || data.Type == "full") return;

foreach (var attch in message.Attachments.OfType<FileAttachment>().Select(attachment => attachment))
{
    // Logic here: returns the attachments info to the webpage
}
```

Is there a better way to get the full attachments list, using the Office.JS API?

Comment: Your suggestion that this is related to blocking executable files is reasonable. That said, the documentation clearly implies it should be returning all the attachments (which EWS seems to do for you). Since either the documentation and/or the library isn't behavior consistently, I've opened a [bug](https://github.com/OfficeDev/office-js/issues/94).

Comment: Thanks for the bug report! The documentation doesn't say anything about not being able to get dangerous / suspicious files, I assumed that I could get everything. It makes sense from a security viewpoint to not be able to get any executable but the docs should clearly say it.